# Dispatching CQRS messages in Node.js

Tags: node.js, rxjs, cqrs, mediator, mediatr

I want to do CQRS for a Node app.

I'm not a Node person, I'm from .NET, which has an excellent library called MediatR which dispatches commands/queries to a mediator that can be used to decouple requests and handlers. So it allows very simple and elegant CQRS.

In the Node world I found many libraries/blogs but they always include Event Sourcing too. I'm not interested in ES.

I can model the commands and queries nicely, but then what? They need to be dispatched somewhere, in a decoupled way to avoid a mess.

From what I know so far about the Node platform, a possible solution is to use the observer pattern (via the RxJs library), so a controller can dispatch messages (i.e. CQRS requests) to an observer, which then publishes corresponding events for subscribers (i.e. request handlers). This decouples controllers and  services in a DDD-like design. Though I'm not sure how to pass results back to the controller.

Is this how other people are doing it? Is there a better way in Node?

Comment: To you want to keep the communication intra-process or do you want to have some kind of other services ?

Comment: @PierreCriulanscy I prefer to keep it simple and only have one process (i.e. Node), and avoid rabbitmq, redis, etc.

Comment: So you can use `redux`, very lightweight, you can dispatch "commands" and intercept them in `redux` middleware. I don't know if you're familiar with `redux` or not.

Comment: You can also have a look to [wolkenkit](https://www.wolkenkit.io/) but it's event sourced too.

Comment: @PierreCriulanscy It's unfortunate there is nothing like this already. I will investigate redux... hopefully it's good enough. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need a complex framework to use CQRS architecture, `redux` is a very good fit :)

Comment: I recommend to use  RxJS observers, you can use very complex event stream logic easily with it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL:DR** : You don't need some fancy framework, especially when you're only doing intra-process communication, to apply CQRS architecture. The native [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) from the `events` module is enough. If you want inter-process communication [`servicebus`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/servicebus) does a really good job. To take a look at an implementation exemple (of the following long version answer) you can dive into the code of this repository : [simple node cqrs](https://github.com/PCreations/simple-node-cqrs)

Let's take an example of a very simple Chat application where you can send messages if the Chat is not closed, and like/unlike messages.

Our main aggregate (or aggregate root, conceptually), is the `Chat` (`writeModel/domain/chat.js`):

```
const Chat = ({ id, isClosed } = {}) =>
  Object.freeze({
    id,
    isClosed,
  });
```

Then, we have a `Message` aggregate (`writeModel/domain/message.js`) :

```
const Message = ({ id, chatId, userId, content, sentAt, messageLikes = [] } = {}) =>
  Object.freeze({
    id,
    chatId,
    userId,
    content,
    sentAt,
    messageLikes,
  });
```

The behavior for sending a message could be (`writeModel/domain/chat.js`) :

```
const invariant = require('invariant');
const { Message } = require('./message');

const Chat = ({ id, isClosed } = {}) =>
  Object.freeze({
    id,
    isClosed,
  });

const sendMessage = ({ chatState, messageId, userId, content, sentAt }) => {
  invariant(!chatState.isClosed, "can't post in a closed chat");
  return Message({ id: messageId, chatId: chatState.id, userId, content, sentAt });
};
```

We now need the commands (`writeModel/domain/commands.js`) :

```
const commands = {
  types: {
    SEND_MESSAGE: '[chat] send a message',
  },
  sendMessage({ chatId, userId, content, sentAt }) {
    return Object.freeze({
      type: commands.types.SEND_MESSAGE,
      payload: {
        chatId,
        userId,
        content,
        sentAt,
      },
    });
  },
};

module.exports = {
  commands,
};
```

Since we're in javascript, we do not have `interface` to provide abstraction so we use `higher order functions` (`writeModel/domain/getChatOfId.js`) :

```
const { Chat } = require('./message');

const getChatOfId = (getChatOfId = async id => Chat({ id })) => async id => {
  try {
    const chatState = await getChatOfId(id);
    if (typeof chatState === 'undefined') {
      throw chatState;
    }
    return chatState;
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(`chat with id ${id} was not found`);
  }
};

module.exports = {
  getChatOfId,
};
```

(`writeModel/domain/saveMessage.js`) :

```
const { Message } = require('./message');

const saveMessage = (saveMessage = async (messageState = Message()) => {}) => saveMessage;

module.exports = {
  saveMessage,
};
```

We need now to implement our `commandHandlers` (the application service layer) :

(`writeModel/commandHandlers/handleSendMessage.js`)

```
const { sendMessage } = require('../domain/chat');

const handleSendMessage = ({
  getChatOfId,
  getNextMessageId,
  saveMessage,
}) => async sendMessageCommandPayload => {
  const { chatId, userId, content, sentAt } = sendMessageCommandPayload;
  const chat = await getChatOfId(chatId);
  return saveMessage(
    sendMessage({
      chatState: chat,
      messageId: getNextMessageId(),
      userId,
      content,
      sentAt,
    }),
  );
};

module.exports = {
  handleSendMessage,
};
```

Since we don't have `interface` in javascript, we use `higher order functions` to apply the Dependency Inversion Principle via injection of the dependencies at runtime.

We can then implement the composition root of the write model : (`writeModel/index.js) :

```
const { handleSendMessage } = require('./commandHandlers/handleSendMessage');
const { commands } = require('./domain/commands');

const SimpleNodeCQRSwriteModel = ({
  dispatchCommand,
  handleCommand,
  getChatOfId,
  getNextMessageId,
  saveMessage,
}) => {
  handleCommand(
    commands.types.SEND_MESSAGE,
    handleSendMessage({ getChatOfId, getNextMessageId, saveMessage }),
  );
};

module.exports = {
  SimpleNodeCQRSwriteModel,
};
```

Your `commands` and `command handler` are not tied together, you can then provide an implementation of these functions at runtime, with an in memory database and the node `EventEmitter` for example (`writeModel/infrastructure/inMemory/index.js`) :

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v1');
const { saveMessage } = require('../../domain/saveMessage');
const { getChatOfId } = require('../../domain/getChatOfId');
const { getNextMessageId } = require('../../domain/getNextMessageId');

const InMemoryRepository = (initialDbState = { chats: {}, messages: {}, users: {} }) => {
  const listeners = [];

  const db = {
    ...initialDbState,
  };

  const addOnDbUpdatedListener = onDbUpdated => listeners.push(onDbUpdated);

  const updateDb = updater => {
    updater();
    listeners.map(listener => listener(db));
  };

  const saveMessageInMemory = saveMessage(async messageState => {
    updateDb(() => (db.messages[messageState.id] = messageState));
  });

  const getChatOfIdFromMemory = getChatOfId(async id => db.chats[id]);

  const getNextMessageUuid = getNextMessageId(uuid);

  return {
    addOnDbUpdatedListener,
    saveMessage: saveMessageInMemory,
    getChatOfId: getChatOfIdFromMemory,
    getNextMessageId: getNextMessageUuid,
  };
};

module.exports = {
  InMemoryRepository,
};
```

And our `TestWriteModel` tying it all together :

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const { SimpleNodeCQRSwriteModel } = require('../writeModel');
const { InMemoryRepository } = require('../writeModel/infrastructure/inMemory');

const TestWriteModel = () => {
  const { saveMessage, getChatOfId, getNextMessageId } = InMemoryRepository();
  const commandEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  const dispatchCommand = command => commandEmitter.emit(command.type, command.payload);
  const handleCommand = (commandType, commandHandler) => {
    commandEmitter.on(commandType, commandHandler);
  };
  return SimpleNodeCQRSwriteModel({
    dispatchCommand,
    handleCommand,
    getChatOfId,
    getNextMessageId,
    saveMessage,
  });
};
```

You can dive into the code (with a very simple `read model`) in this repository : [simple node cqrs](https://github.com/PCreations/simple-node-cqrs)

Comment: Fantastically detailed answer... Merci Pierre!

Comment: You're welcome ! I'm gonna write on this very topic soon, so just took some advance haha ;)

Comment: I will rewrite it with TypeScript so then I can use my various interfaces. Then it's gonna be perfect. :)

Comment: You might be interested by this medium post then : [Patterns for designing flexible architecture in node.js (CQRS/ES/Onion)](https://medium.com/@domagojk/patterns-for-designing-flexible-architecture-in-node-js-cqrs-es-onion-7eb10bbefe17)